# static html page access checking by php

Tags: php, session

I want to restrict access for users to their specific data.
The site is all static html with a minimum of php to check if a user has permission.
The url format is
    somesite.tld/public_html/english/user/1/account_overview.php?id=1
The site is available in some languages. the 'english' part of the url will change according to chosen language (french, german, dutch, ...). The 'english' part is a folder in public_html. The 'user' part is a folder in 'english' and the '1' is folder in 'user'.

I have a $_SESSION['userid']. 
At this moment the php script checks if the $_GET['id'] exists and if $_GET['id'] is equal to the $_SESSION['userid']
but just changing the url to 
    somesite.tld/public_html/english/user/2/account_overview.php?id=1
does not limit the access to the '2' folder if you are logged in with userid = 1.

how can I stop displaying the data when someone modifies the url manually ?

Comment: Can you change the url format? Best option here might be to eliminate the GET query altogether. Just use the $_SESSION.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you avoid this altogether. Rather than using a $_GET variable to determine if the user has permissions to view the account, why not just use one PHP retrieval script that uses the session variable to get the user's account.

It would go something like this:

You have all of the account files stored in a directory that is read protected, like:

```
/accounts/
```

Then in your PHP file:

```
session_start();
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/accounts/".$_SESSION["userid"].".html");
```

This will avoid the issue altogether. By read-protecting the directory to all except the PHP user, you can prevent people from accessing the files without being logged in. Then you don't have any loose $_GET variables and all of the account info is secure.

Comment: The php login script gets the userid. Thank you. I did not think about using include(). I was stuck on trying to validate the url format.

Comment: to make this work and secure I will have to save the contents with the user information outside the public_html folder, I think.
So I am going to make a user_account.php page and that page will get the static generated content from outside the public_html folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is in your AccountController or account.php,

```
if($userId != $superAdminId || $userId != $_SESSION["userid"]){
    //set error header
    //show error 401
}
```